# php-regex inserting zero before decimal

Tags: php, regex

Decimals: Use leading zero (0.4), P values less than 1 are set without a leading zero (P = .05)

```
<?php
    // Leading zero for decimals
    $match='
    .5
    p=.5
    a= 67
    687.689
    .90 the decimal digit is
    .56 ';
    if (preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\s]+)?(?<!p=)(?<!\d)(\.(\d{1,}))/',$match))
    {
        $replacement = '$1&nbsp;0$2';
        $replac = preg_replace('/([a-z A-Z\s]+)?(?<!p=)(?<!\d)(\.(\d{1,}))/', $replacement, $match);
        echo $replac;
    }
    else
        echo $match;
?>
```

Input:

```
.5
p=.5
a=.67
687.689
.90
the decimal digit is .56
```

Output:

```
0.5 p=.5 a= 0.67 687.689  0.90 the decimal digit is  0.56
```

The output is correct, but if I insert space in the input near `p = .5`, the output becomes like this:

```
 0.5 p =  0.5 a= 0.67 687.689  0.90 the decimal digit is  0.56
```

Zero shouldn't be added for p = .5

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Easy, change the count for the decimals like this:

```
/([^p]\s+[=]+\s+)(\.\d{1,})/
```

EDIT:
Now is clear what you want, this new string take this input:

```
a = .1 p = .5
```

and gives you:

```
a = 0.1 p = .5
```

Comment: `{2,}`How does it mean??

Comment: @Matteo that is not a problem here,if i give input like this p = .5 my output becomes p = 0.5 this is not the expected one. the output should be p = .5

Comment: @ling.s means at least 2, the current regexp check for at least 1 ({1,}) and will always match .5

Comment: @user3064914 The above regexp string will not transform .5 into 0.5

Comment: @Matteo if i give above regexp my output becomes like this ".5 p=.5 a=.67 687.689  0.90 the decimal digit is  0.56" this not the expected one for p = .5 alone there should be no leading zero.

Comment: @user3064914 as you asked, yes

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the answer for my question. It may not be a better one, but it gives the expected result.

```
if (preg_match('/([a-zA-Z\s]+)?(?<!p\s=\s)(?<!p=\s)(?<!p\s=)(?<!p=)(?<!\d)(\.(\d{1,}))/', $match))
{
...
}
```

Input:

```
p = .5 a = .5
```

Output:

```
p = .5 a = 0.5
```